# Quantifier (+‘of things’) + verb

Tags: partitives

> A couple of people objected to the proposal, but **the vast majority** approved of it.

https://www.google.com/amp/s/dictionary.cambridge.org/us/amp/english/majority

‘The vast majority’ instead of ‘the vast majority of things/people’

Can I just say, ‘two jump,’ ‘the minority jump,’ ‘a good/great deal jump,’ and ‘a couple jump’? I mean, can I omit the following phrase ‘of things’ in English?

Comment: _People_ occurs in the first phrase, so _the vast majority_ is understood to mean _of people_. Your phrases would only work if you had made it clear 'two _of whom_' - 'a great deal _of what_'. ('Couple' is a bit different, as the default meaning is 'a married couple'.)

Comment: @Kate Bunting I thought ‘the’+quantifier makes a concrete noun like ‘the’+adjective, thanks.

Comment: @Kate Bunting It happens in Korean too, but you know, in Korean, even a subject or object can be omitted, so I was confused.

Comment: Yes, but _the minority_ only makes sense if you have previously indicated what larger group it's a minority of!